# Is it appropriate to avoid family members who don't practice, and whose behavior is "evil"?

Tags: family

I am a Muslim who has family members which are not practicing Islam. They have witnessed clear signs of Allah like someone being possessed with Jinn and reacting to the recitation of the Qur'an but they turned away and did not change their ways. They still persist in sin and transgression in forms like: Not praying (some not praying at all while others pray irregularly), drinking alcohol, not covering themselves, going to the magicians and asking them, spraying water of magicians in their homes, celebrating the festivals of the disbelievers, making friends with them, not attending Jumah, completely shaving the beards.

They claim to be Muslims and they saw clear signs of Allah that they need to return but still refuse. I fear for myself because they are involved in going to the magicians and I fear that they may harm me because of their superstitious lifestyle. They accused me of being the cause of their problems although I am a practicing Muslims who does not visit magicians and causes harm to the people. Alhamdulillah.

They accused me and my mother in the past of horrible things and we are not sure if it is safe to go to them because of them being involved in going to magicians. They started to sever ties by not helping us in times of hardship and ignoring our problems and not visiting us during these times. It is almost 4,5 years that these people persist in sin and transgression and severing ties. They are today basically known for their evil and this is why we avoid them. My and mother have developed a deep hatred for the sake of Allah because these people commit sins openly during the day and they don't care.

Is it permissible for me to avoid them as long as they don't repent to Allah and mend their ways? Or am I sinful? These people know about prayer, fasting and so on but they refuse to practice Islam correctly out of their own choice not because of ignorance.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. I strongls suggest you to take our [tour], visit our [help] and read [ask] to learn more about the Stack Exchange model and how this site works. Allah says: "And be patient over what they say and avoid them with gracious avoidance." http://legacy.quran.com/73

Answer (score 1):

We are not a fatwa site, nor your peer advisors so I will not give you advice on your particular situation.

In general it is permissible to avoid or boycott a sinner. And this is especially if they commit sins openly, and if you do not have any other way of changing their behavior, and if you will be harmed in your religion or otherwise by interacting with them.

The Prophet ﷺ and the Muslims avoided three sahaba for fifty days because of their negligence in not participating in Tabuk expedition. This is mentioned in the Quran ([9:118](https://quran.com/9/118?translations=20)) and in the lengthy hadith of Ka'b bin Malik that is recorded in both [Bukhari and Muslim](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:21)). And scholars have derived the permissibility of doing so from this event and others, such as [Abu Dawud 4916](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4916) and [Muslim 1954](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1954d).

> فيه هجران أهل البدع والفسوق ومنابذي السنة مع العلم وأنه يجوز هجرانه دائما والنهي عن الهجران فوق ثلاثة أيام إنما هو فيمن هجر لحظ نفسه ومعايش الدنيا
>
> It is permissible to perpetually avoid the ahl al-Biddah, and the Fasiqeen and those who knowingly disregard the Sunnah. The prohibition of avoiding for more than three days is only applicable to one who does so for personal or worldly reasons
>
> <sup>— [Sharah Sahih Muslim - Nawawi](https://shamela.ws/book/1711/2916)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**The answer might lay in the Qunoot dua**

I think you might be familiar with the translation of the Qunoot dua, however, here is a link to it as reference: https://www.islamicfinder.org/duas/masnoon/dua-e-qunoot-recited-in-witr-prayer/

When making this dua you are clearly stating that you alienate and forsake those who disobey Allah almighty.

I don't know if this is the clear answer for your case, however, one thing is sure, there is never a do or not do, there's always some kind of compromise between them. for example, you should try to understand in which way you should do what you do (whether you choose to alienate and forsake them or keep your connections) to do not cause any harm (of any kind) or fitnah.

Answer (score -1):

From your question, I feel you are trying to follow the footsteps of Prophet Muhammed (SAW). As far as you follow his way, you don't  want to avoid anyone because our prophet never avoided anyone in any situation rather he tried to change them in two ways: (1) made dua to Allah to show them the right path and (2) kept on giving dawah.

I personally advise you to make your Eemaan strong as possible, know which is real haram and halal, and maintain strong relationship between you and Allah. If you are lacking with that, you might be misguided. After making a strong relationship, you can start giving dawah to them. **Make sure you do dua before giving dawah**.