# Why did prophet muhammad pbuh hit aisha ra (his wife) and make her have pain

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, men-women

In this [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:334) prophet muhammad a.s hit aisha since I'm guessing she make them be stuck in area without any water but why did he make it painful tho?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it ok for parents to hit their children?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69100/is-it-ok-for-parents-to-hit-their-children)

Comment: The hadith nowhere said that the prophet hit 'Aishah.

Comment: But aisha isn't prophet muhammad a.s child though

Answer (score 0):

It was Abu Bakr, not the prophet. Also, (I'm pretty sure) there was a war and the troops of the Prophet were held back because Aisha lost the necklace and the prophet (PBUH) stopped everyone to find the necklace. If you were a father and your daughter was the reason why everyone was held back, you would probably feel responsible and ashamed.

Comment: Allah swt is the most merciful and most forgiving may Allah swt guide to Islam and forgive all you sins make you go jannat al firadus highest rank of heaven and you family and friends as well may Allah swt guide them both and you aswell Ameen❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤

Comment: Thank you my beloved brother and may you gain that reward as well ameen❤❤❤